# How to disable special history editing on bash command line

Tags: terminal, bash, history

The letter `g` at the end of a path entry in either `Terminal` or `iTerm2` is being captured and processed - I think by `bash`.  Here is what typing `cd /git/ciderg` looks like:

[image]

Notice the `g` is not typed.  If I type `ESC` it does show:

[image]

But if I hit `g` again it looks like some kind of `history` editing happens: a command from way long ago is posted and replaces the command I was typing

It seems that `gg` is being something like `History | Go to beginning` .  How do I disable that?

I had already removed the `~/.vimrc`  and `~/.vim` directory.  I do use `set -o vi` but that had been working for years - and without this strangeness.

Comment: Turn off vi mode in bash?

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes I should have addressed that in the question.  I have used `vi mode` for many years without this happening - must be some setting to disable on it ?

Comment: No idea.  Haven't used bash for many years, I use ksh.

Comment: Do you have a ~/.inputrc file?

Comment: @GordonDavisson aha!  Pls make that an answer .  Here is the culprit  `"gg": beginning-of-history`

Comment: @javadba I'm inclined to mark this is a duplicate, since there are a number of variants of this problem already here. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275010/my-terminal-on-osx-10-11-6-will-not-accept-character) is probably best. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238002/in-terminal-i-cannot-type-lowercase-e) might be closer, but doesn't have an accepted answer. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/why-does-terminal-ignore-capital-b) one does have an accepted answer, but it's a bad recommendation.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for searching for the duplicates. I've included the third link as well, it gives some insights into how to analyze issues like the one described in the question.